# Raspberry Pi Zero reboot after some AT commands to A6 gsm modem through serial

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, serial-port, gsm

I have a problem with Raspberry Pi Zero 1.3 and A6 GSM modem. When I send speciffically commands which should communicate with the sim card on the gsm module (like AT+CGATT=1), the raspberry reboots with no entries in the logs pointing to the reboot. I am running latest Raspbian Lite.

Modem is connected to the Serial port on raspberry (Tx+Rx) and also 5V and Gnd. Raspberry is powered by 1,5A power supply through USB (pwr).

This errors also when Tx from GSM module is disconnected (so no received answer on raspberry).

I have tried changing the modem modules, but the error still occurs. I have also changed raspberry boards and the error seems to be absent on some boards.

Have any of you encountered something similar?

Here is my testing code in python:

```
import time
import serial
import sys
import os

print "Starting program"
os.system('echo raspberry | stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 9600')

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600,
                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
                    timeout=5
                    )
time.sleep(1)
try:
    while True:
        input = raw_input('Give me command master: ')
        ser.write(input + '\r\n')
        data = ser.read(10000)
        print data

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Exiting Program"

except:
    print "Error Occurs, Exiting Program"

finally:
    ser.close()
    pass
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure your voltage connections are correct?  5V seems high for an *"A6 GSM modem"*.